# Can we run our python program using python scheduler by deploying in google cloud platform?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I have been trying to run a program using cloud functions, task scheduler and cron jobs scheduler. But, I am not getting what files or exact configuration in those cron.yaml file. There is parameter called (url), I don't know what path should I include in that. So, I am trying to deploy the program in GCP by including python scheduler. Or could anyone help by telling me what should I include in that cron.yaml file?

Comment: Split your issues. Can you run your Cloud Functions? If so, what scheduling do you want to perform? We can guide you (and forget the cron.yaml, it's for App Engine and it's deprecated!)